# Example of a function $f(x,t)$ such that $t \to \int f(x,t) dx$ and $\int f(x,t) dxdt$ finite, BUT $\int \lvert f(x,t) \rvert dxdt =\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, examples-counterexamples

Let $f(x,t) : [0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function such that
\begin{equation}
x \to f(x, t) \text{ is integrable for a.e. } t \in [0,1]
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
t \to \int_0^1 f(x,t) dx \text{ is a.e. finite and nonnegative }
\end{equation}
plus
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x,t) dx dt \text{ is finite}.
\end{equation}

Under such conditions, is it still possible to have
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 \lvert f(x,t)\rvert dx dt = \infty?
\end{equation}

I believe so, but cannot easily come up with an example myself.. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously need to take a function $f$ not integrable, otherwise this would be impossible by Fubini's theorem. I suggest you take a classical counterexample to Fubini in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Failure_of_Fubini%27s_theorem_for_non-integrable_functions). Namely consider, $$f(x,t)=\frac{t^2-x^2}{(t^2+x^2)^2}.$$

You can see that $\int_0^1 f(x,t)dx = \frac{1}{1+t^2}$ and $\int_0^1 f(x,t)dt = \frac{-1}{1+x^2}$. Since $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx= arctan(1)$, you get that integrating in a different order gives different values, so the function must not be integrable. In this case, you also have that $\int_0^1 f(x,t)dx \geq 0$ for all $t>0$.

**Edit:**

Following the discussion in the comments, we can also see that $$\int_0^1\vert f(x,t)\vert dx \geq \int_0^t \vert f(x,t)\vert dx=\int_0^t  f(x,t) dx.$$

The last term is equal to $\frac{t}{2t^2}=\frac{1}{2t}$. We know that $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2t}= \infty$.

Comment: By non-integrable, you mean that $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \lvert f(x,t) \rvert dxdt = \infty$ just like I wrote in my question?

Comment: I am trying to show this directly for your function, but it seems a bit tricky... Could you perhaps delineate further on $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \lvert f(x,t) \rvert dxdt = \infty$ for your function?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean by non-integrable. By Tonelli's theorem, you know that $\int_{[0,1]^2}\vert f(x,t)\vert=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \lvert f(x,t) \rvert dxdt$. The left hand side is what people usually mean by non integrable. I did not show it by definition, but since $[0,1]^2$ is sigma-finite, it must not be integrable.

Comment: Ok. I am currently trying to show $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \lvert f(x,t) \rvert dxdt = \infty$ for your function directly by estimating the lower bound. Of course, contrapositive of Fubini Thereom implies this fact, as you pointed out.

Comment: @Keith I added an argument that might help as an edit.